# How to make custom shaped holes in terrain

Tags: c#, unity

So I'm trying to create a game where you fit certain shaped objects into the hole that fits them (similar to the young children's game with different shaped blocks) in Unity 3D.

I've encountered a problem, how do I make the holes in the terrain? Or what type of object should I use for making holes in?

So far I've tried to make a 3d model in unity by using other cubes and planes, it just doesn't feel right.
I guess I need to create a model in another software and import to unity, I don't know any other software I can use. Tips would help.

Comment: You should use something other than terrain - that's for sure. I would recommend rewording your question though, are you talking about drag or drop or talking about the "hole in terrain" concept. Be specific and try and direct it with a technical question.

Comment: I removed your extra question, as that should be asked separately. You say you've encountered this problem, you should update the question to explain what you've tried so far, and what about it didn't work. As for which object type to use, that depends entirely on the design of your game. You could use terrain or you could make a model in a separate program and import it. Up to you.

Comment: I've tried to create a model from other cubes and planes, it's just doesn't work out for me.

Comment: Generally speaking unity does not do holes. You can change the elevation of the terrain to make parts deeper than others using the raise/lower terrain tool in the terrain editor but if you want to create a more complex terrain you are going to have to import it as a model. You could create things from cubes in Unity but that is usually a lot more work than just creating a terrain in modeling tool (Maya, Blender, 3D Studio Max, etc.) and importing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a plugin for this on the Asset Store: [Terrain Hole System](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/8277)

Description: “This Unity extension lets you make holes in your terrain that characters and other objects can go through.”

More information can be found on the [forum thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/182094-Terrain-Hole-System).